# add / remove class not removing class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click function set for a video slider gallery, when i click the main video play / or pause I am trying to add a class "active--thumbnail" to the corresponding thumbnail. It is working and adding the class. When I click the main video again it is not removing the class. Not sure where I am going wrong here, any advice?

jquery:

```
$('.video-main').on('click', function () {
var mainVideoIndex = $('.video-main').index(this),
activeThumbnail = $(this).closest('.video-playlist').find('.l-thumbnail__title').eq(mainVideoIndex),

$('.l-thumbnail__title').not(activeThumbnail).removeClass('active--thumbnail');
activeThumbnail.addClass('active--thumbnail');

});
```

Comment: Do you have a sandbox you can share for this?

Comment: The last line of your click handler is `activeThumbnail.addClass('active--thumbnail');` so when clicking on the same thumb as you previously did, will not remove the active class. You need to check if the clicked element already has active or not and do what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the clicked item has the active class or not then proceed to add or remove the active class

I borrowed the html and css from the other answer

```js
$('.video-main').on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var mainVideoIndex = $('.video-main').index(this),
    activeThumbnail = $this.closest('.video-playlist').find('.l-thumbnail__title').eq(mainVideoIndex);

  // check if the clicked is the same as currently active item
  // if it is then remove active
  if (activeThumbnail.hasClass('active--thumbnail')) {
    activeThumbnail.removeClass('active--thumbnail');
  }
  // remove active from all thumbs titles then add active to clicked item
  else {
    $('.l-thumbnail__title').removeClass('active--thumbnail');
    activeThumbnail.addClass('active--thumbnail');
  }
});
```

```css
ul.video-playlist li p {
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.active--thumbnail {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="video-playlist">
    <li>
        <p class="l-thumbnail__title">Thumbnail 1</p>
        <button class="video-main">Video 1</button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p class="l-thumbnail__title">Thumbnail 2</p>
        <button class="video-main">Video 2</button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p class="l-thumbnail__title">Thumbnail 3</p>
        <button class="video-main">Video 3</button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p class="l-thumbnail__title">Thumbnail 4</p>
        <button class="video-main">Video 4</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add a Codepen to know you HTML code.

But I see a (,) instead of a (;) in line 3.

```
$('.video-main').on('click', function () {
var mainVideoIndex = $('.video-main').index(this),
    activeThumbnail = $(this).closest('.video-playlist').find('.l-thumbnail__title').eq(mainVideoIndex);

$('.l-thumbnail__title').not(activeThumbnail).removeClass('active--thumbnail');
activeThumbnail.addClass('active--thumbnail');
```

});

See this https://codepen.io/AngelFQC/pen/RwPLygm

Comment: Actually there is no need to add codepen, there is a snippet button which can be used to create working code on here